# What exactly is inflammation?

Tags: infection, inflammation

If I get stung by a bee, I'll have inflammation in that area. But I've seen inflammation mentioned in the context of the whole body.

What is this invisible inflammation, and how can its presence be detected in absence of symptoms such as a skin rash?

Comment: What's tixinsy?

Comment: @Lucky looks like he meant to type `toxins`.

Comment: @briantist yes, that makes more sense :-). @ Dan sorry I misinterpreted your question, but it is still very broad. Mechanism of toxicity for most toxins isn't inflammation, but people ("health gurus") classify all sorts of substances as toxins. Can you narrow it down a bit to a class of substances (or a specific substance) or better yet link a webpage with the sort of claims you would like to be clarified? Without more details I'm afraid that we're stuck.

Comment: This is such an underappreciated question. Here's this topic at the heart of most human disease, and a request by presumably someone outside of the medical field for a better understanding of it, and it's only got 6 upvotes

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find all the information you search for in [this book](http://tinyurl.com/p59wnjo) (there are plenty out there on the subject).

Anyway in brief terms **inflammation is a reaction of the body to a deleterious event** (eg too hot, too cold, dangerous chemicals, radiation, toxins etc) that could happen on a small (cellular level), or large scale (organ level) and in a little (a paper cut), or long time (chronic diseases) and provokes **cellular damage**.

It involves a **cellular** and **humoral** response but it's really a big issue, difficult to solve in just a post.

The invisible inflammation you mentioned falls in this field, but it depends on the specific subject since inflammation is involved in practically all the human diseases.

[An example](http://tinyurl.com/p2h2zjm)

Hope it helps

EDIT
i changed the second link since it was not freely available to everyone.

Comment: Your second link requires a paid subscription to access.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the site. Nice book link. In general, though, relying on links to do most of the explaining is not standard on Stack Exchange sites; an answer in your own words supported by a link is regarded as a better answer. Your answer boils down to "inflammation is a reaction of the body to a deleterious event involving a cellular and [h?]umoral response." That's not too informative. Please see the [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about the site.

Comment: Yes you're right, unfortunately i do not have much time to cover the topic properly... next time it will be better.

Comment: @CareyGregory Oh, i'm sorry since i am a university student so i can have access to that paper... i think to have found a substitute even if probably more specific: http://tinyurl.com/p2h2zjm